# kazam control window disappears when capture starts

Tags: video-editor, desktop-recording, kazam

I need to record a window on ubuntu 20.04. I installed kazam and selected window and started capture. But as soon as the recording starts, the kazam control window disappears. The manual says I should press super+ctrl+F but I don't know how to find super key. I'm using Korea keyboard and accessing my ubuntu maching using vnc. So I tried to do it on graphical console window. Now I can press super+ctrl+F and the kazam window appears asking me if I want to save the recorded content to a file. This is very dangerous and inconvenient. Why does the kazam window disappear? (at first, small icon was visible in the activies on the top left. but not anymore) What if I forget I was recording a window and the program records the window endlessly? Is there any option to make the kazam window not disappear? Thanks!